# Detecting right or middle mouse button double-click in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Flutter already contains the

- `onSecondaryTap` property for the right mouse button single-click detection,
- `onTertiaryTap` property for the middle mouse button single-click detection and
- `onDoubleTap` property for the left mouse button double-click detection.

Does Flutter also contain properties for right or middle mouse button double-click detection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in GestureDetector in Flutter does not contain properties for onDoubleSecondary tap or onDoubleTertiaryTap but you can create your own Gesture recognizers and add them to a RawGestureDetector.

Here is a GestureRecognizer that recognizes double right-clicks:

```
class _CountdownZoned {
  _CountdownZoned({ required Duration duration })
      : assert(duration != null) {
    Timer(duration, _onTimeout);
  }

  bool _timeout = false;

  bool get timeout => _timeout;

  void _onTimeout() {
    _timeout = true;
  }
}

class _TapTracker {
  _TapTracker({
    required PointerDownEvent event,
    required this.entry,
    required Duration doubleTapMinTime,
    required this.gestureSettings,
  }) : assert(doubleTapMinTime != null),
        assert(event != null),
        assert(event.buttons != null),
        pointer = event.pointer,
        _initialGlobalPosition = event.position,
        initialButtons = event.buttons,
        _doubleTapMinTimeCountdown = _CountdownZoned(duration: doubleTapMinTime);

  final DeviceGestureSettings? gestureSettings;
  final int pointer;
  final GestureArenaEntry entry;
  final Offset _initialGlobalPosition;
  final int initialButtons;
  final _CountdownZoned _doubleTapMinTimeCountdown;

  bool _isTrackingPointer = false;

  void startTrackingPointer(PointerRoute route, Matrix4? transform) {
    if (!_isTrackingPointer) {
      _isTrackingPointer = true;
      GestureBinding.instance.pointerRouter.addRoute(pointer, route, transform);
    }
  }

  void stopTrackingPointer(PointerRoute route) {
    if (_isTrackingPointer) {
      _isTrackingPointer = false;
      GestureBinding.instance.pointerRouter.removeRoute(pointer, route);
    }
  }

  bool isWithinGlobalTolerance(PointerEvent event, double tolerance) {
    final Offset offset = event.position - _initialGlobalPosition;
    return offset.distance <= tolerance;
  }

  bool hasElapsedMinTime() {
    return _doubleTapMinTimeCountdown.timeout;
  }

  bool hasSameButton(PointerDownEvent event) {
    return event.buttons == initialButtons;
  }
}

class DoubleRightClick extends GestureRecognizer {
  DoubleRightClick({
    super.debugOwner,
    @Deprecated(
      'Migrate to supportedDevices. '
          'This feature was deprecated after v2.3.0-1.0.pre.',
    )
    super.kind,
    super.supportedDevices,
  });

  GestureTapDownCallback? onDoubleTapDown;
  GestureDoubleTapCallback? onDoubleTap;
  GestureTapCancelCallback? onDoubleTapCancel;

  Timer? _doubleTapTimer;
  _TapTracker? _firstTap;
  final Map<int, _TapTracker> _trackers = <int, _TapTracker>{};

  @override
  bool isPointerAllowed(PointerDownEvent event) {
    if (_firstTap == null) {
      switch (event.buttons) {
        case kSecondaryMouseButton:
          if (onDoubleTapDown == null &&
              onDoubleTap == null &&
              onDoubleTapCancel == null) {
            return false;
          }
          break;
        default:
          return false;
      }
    }
    return super.isPointerAllowed(event);
  }

  @override
  void addAllowedPointer(PointerDownEvent event) {
    if (_firstTap != null) {
      if (!_firstTap!.isWithinGlobalTolerance(event, kDoubleTapSlop)) {
        // Ignore out-of-bounds second taps.
        return;
      } else if (!_firstTap!.hasElapsedMinTime() || !_firstTap!.hasSameButton(event)) {
        // Restart when the second tap is too close to the first (touch screens
        // often detect touches intermittently), or when buttons mismatch.
        _reset();
        return _trackTap(event);
      } else if (onDoubleTapDown != null) {
        final TapDownDetails details = TapDownDetails(
          globalPosition: event.position,
          localPosition: event.localPosition,
          kind: getKindForPointer(event.pointer),
        );
        invokeCallback<void>('onDoubleTapDown', () => onDoubleTapDown!(details));
      }
    }
    _trackTap(event);
  }

  void _trackTap(PointerDownEvent event) {
    _stopDoubleTapTimer();
    final _TapTracker tracker = _TapTracker(
      event: event,
      entry: GestureBinding.instance.gestureArena.add(event.pointer, this),
      doubleTapMinTime: kDoubleTapMinTime,
      gestureSettings: gestureSettings,
    );
    _trackers[event.pointer] = tracker;
    tracker.startTrackingPointer(_handleEvent, event.transform);
  }

  void _handleEvent(PointerEvent event) {
    final _TapTracker tracker = _trackers[event.pointer]!;
    if (event is PointerUpEvent) {
      if (_firstTap == null) {
        _registerFirstTap(tracker);
      } else {
        _registerSecondTap(tracker);
      }
    } else if (event is PointerMoveEvent) {
      if (!tracker.isWithinGlobalTolerance(event, kDoubleTapTouchSlop)) {
        _reject(tracker);
      }
    } else if (event is PointerCancelEvent) {
      _reject(tracker);
    }
  }

  @override
  void acceptGesture(int pointer) { }

  @override
  void rejectGesture(int pointer) {
    _TapTracker? tracker = _trackers[pointer];
    // If tracker isn't in the list, check if this is the first tap tracker
    if (tracker == null &&
        _firstTap != null &&
        _firstTap!.pointer == pointer) {
      tracker = _firstTap;
    }
    // If tracker is still null, we rejected ourselves already
    if (tracker != null) {
      _reject(tracker);
    }
  }

  void _reject(_TapTracker tracker) {
    _trackers.remove(tracker.pointer);
    tracker.entry.resolve(GestureDisposition.rejected);
    _freezeTracker(tracker);
    if (_firstTap != null) {
      if (tracker == _firstTap) {
        _reset();
      } else {
        _checkCancel();
        if (_trackers.isEmpty) {
          _reset();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _reset();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _reset() {
    _stopDoubleTapTimer();
    if (_firstTap != null) {
      if (_trackers.isNotEmpty) {
        _checkCancel();
      }
      // Note, order is important below in order for the resolve -> reject logic
      // to work properly.
      final _TapTracker tracker = _firstTap!;
      _firstTap = null;
      _reject(tracker);
      GestureBinding.instance.gestureArena.release(tracker.pointer);
    }
    _clearTrackers();
  }

  void _registerFirstTap(_TapTracker tracker) {
    _startDoubleTapTimer();
    GestureBinding.instance.gestureArena.hold(tracker.pointer);
    // Note, order is important below in order for the clear -> reject logic to
    // work properly.
    _freezeTracker(tracker);
    _trackers.remove(tracker.pointer);
    _clearTrackers();
    _firstTap = tracker;
  }

  void _registerSecondTap(_TapTracker tracker) {
    _firstTap!.entry.resolve(GestureDisposition.accepted);
    tracker.entry.resolve(GestureDisposition.accepted);
    _freezeTracker(tracker);
    _trackers.remove(tracker.pointer);
    _checkUp(tracker.initialButtons);
    _reset();
  }

  void _clearTrackers() {
    _trackers.values.toList().forEach(_reject);
    assert(_trackers.isEmpty);
  }

  void _freezeTracker(_TapTracker tracker) {
    tracker.stopTrackingPointer(_handleEvent);
  }

  void _startDoubleTapTimer() {
    _doubleTapTimer ??= Timer(kDoubleTapTimeout, _reset);
  }

  void _stopDoubleTapTimer() {
    if (_doubleTapTimer != null) {
      _doubleTapTimer!.cancel();
      _doubleTapTimer = null;
    }
  }

  void _checkUp(int buttons) {
    assert(buttons == kSecondaryMouseButton);
    if (onDoubleTap != null) {
      invokeCallback<void>('onDoubleTap', onDoubleTap!);
    }
  }

  void _checkCancel() {
    if (onDoubleTapCancel != null) {
      invokeCallback<void>('onDoubleTapCancel', onDoubleTapCancel!);
    }
  }

  @override
  String get debugDescription => 'double tap';
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
RawGestureDetector(
            gestures: {
              DoubleRightClick: GestureRecognizerFactoryWithHandlers<DoubleRightClick>(
                () => DoubleRightClick(),
                (DoubleRightClick instance) {
                  instance.onDoubleTap = () {
                    debugPrint('Double Right Click');
                  };
                },
              ),
            },
            child: Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 200,
                height: 200,
                child: FlutterLogo(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

This [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q85LBtBdi0U) from the Flutter team explains how the Gesture arena works.